# Omnipay Integration into Aimeos E-Commerce

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have an integrated payment for purchasing with credit cards. and I want to use omnipay. my required composer.json array is as follows:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "academe/omnipay-adyen": "^3.0",
    "aimeos/ai-payments": "~2019.10",
    "aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2019.10",
    "dilab/omnipay-2c2p": "~2.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^1.2",
    "league/omnipay": "3",
    "omnipay/paypal": "^3.0"
},
```

I did try to use multiple providers with no luck of getting it to work. I've registered a new payment service and I've set the option type to ex: "Adyen" or "2c2p" but after I submit the payment form data it gives me an error class not found for example when I used adyen

```
Class '\Omnipay\adyen\Gateway' not found
```

I did implement the Gateway Class with the relevant Credentials in the Package src folder as follows:

```
class Gateway extends AbstractGateway
{
    use GatewayParameters;

    public function getDefaultParameters()
    {
        return [
            'merchantAccount' => 'null',
            'skinCode' => null,
            'secret' => null,
            'publicKeyToken' => null,
            'username' => null,
            'password' => null,
        ];
    }
}
```

How to setup the payment method?

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` command ? I hope it works.

Comment: no, it still the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
"league/omnipay": "^3"
```

It is correct and it must work. Better if you can remove your vendor folder and install it again.

And here you can see, how to use it - https://github.com/academe/omnipay-adyen